# Ruby - compare two arrays for index matches and with the remainder if included

Tags: arrays, ruby

Working on a project to recreate a game Mastermind. I need to compare two arrays, and running into some struggles.

I need to output two integers for the flow of the game to work,

the first integer is the number of correct choices where the index matches. The code I have for this appears to be working

```rb
  pairs = @code.zip(guess)
  correct_position_count = pairs.select { |pair| pair[0] == pair[1] }.count
```

Where pairs is equal to a 4 element array and the guess is also a 4 element array

The second part I am having a bit of trouble with on how to do the comparison and return an array. The integer should represent where the two arrays index don't match (the above code block but !=) and confirm whether the guess array excluding any exact index matches has any elements included with the code array once again excluding the exact index matches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A bit more detail in the code would help: define all the variables and what you expect the result should be, E.g. 
@code = %w[A B C D E]; 
guess = %w[X B Z D E];
result is expected to be be `[0, 2]` since the 0th and the 2nd index of the guess don't match the @code.

Comment: Note: `[[1,1],[2,3],[3,3]].count { |a,b| a==b } #=> 2`. Or, if `@code = [1,2,3]; guess = [1,3,3]; @code.each_index.count { |i| @code[i] == guess[i] }`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure to understand your problem but if I understood well, you've two arrays, `solution` with the solution and `guess` with the current guess of the player.

Now, let's assume that the solution is `1234` and that the guess is `3335`.

```rb
solution = [1, 2, 3, 4]
guess = [3, 3, 3, 5]
```

an element by element comparison produces an array of booleans.

```rb
diff = guess.map.with_index { |x,i| x == solution[i] }
#    = [false, false, true, false]
```

Now, you can easily compute the number of good digits `diff.count true` and the number of wrong digits `diff.count false`. And, in case you need the index of the `false` and/or `true` values you can do

```rb
diff.each_index.select { |i| diff[i] } # indexes with true
# = [2]
diff.each_index.select { |i| !diff[i] } # indexes with false
# = [0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count all digit matches ignoring their positions and then subtract exact matches.

```rb
pairs = @code.zip(guess)
correct_position_count = pairs.select { |pair| pair[0] == pair[1]}.count

any_position_count = 0
code_digits = @code.clone # protect @code from modifying 
guess.each do |digit|
  if code_digits.include?(digit)
    code_digits.delete_at(code_digits.find_index(digit)) # delete the found digit not to count it more than once
    any_position_count += 1
  end
end
inexact_position_count = any_position_count - correct_position_count

puts "The first value: #{correct_position_count}"
puts "The second value: #{inexact_position_count}"
```